# Critical vulnerability - Prevent azure ad authorization using algorithm none

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, .net-6.0, asp.net-authorization

We are using Azure Ad authorization in .NET 6.0.
Got critical vulnerability where algorithm type cannot be null.

Here's the [guide](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/) which explains why this is critical vulnerability(Shout out to the author for detailed explanation)

This is our implementation:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configuration); 


    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

All the references, we come across is asking to validate the signature.
Now we don't use any secret key Or cert to validate the signature by generating a random HSA OR RSA keys.
Kind of stuck with this vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to manually check if the algorithm was none.
Below is the implementation for which we got a pass from security team:

```
            var jwtData = new DataMap<string>();
        if (Request?.Headers != null)
        {
            _ = AuthenticationHeaderValue.TryParse(Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization], out AuthenticationHeaderValue authValue);
            if (authValue?.Scheme == "Bearer")
            {
                // Decode JWT and extract the claims.
                string token = authValue.Parameter;

                var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                if (jwtHandler.CanReadToken(token))
                {
                    JwtSecurityToken validJwt = GetValidJWT(jwtHandler, token);
                    var claims = validJwt.Claims;
                    foreach (var claim in claims)
                    {
                        jwtData[claim.Type] = claim.Value;
                    }
                    _jwtData = jwtData;
                }
                else
                {
                    jwtData[authValue.Scheme] = token ?? "";
                }
            }
        }


    protected JwtSecurityToken GetValidJWT(JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler, string token)
    {
        JwtSecurityToken validJwt = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);
        //Validate algorithm
        if (validJwt == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid JWT");
        }

        if (!validJwt.Header.Alg.Equals("RS256"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Algorithm must be RS256");
        }
        return validJwt;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The library will validate tokens using RSA keys.
It automatically loads public keys from e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys at app startup.
Those public keys are used to verify the signature of the tokens.
It will not accept tokens without signature unless you override those settings. (at least it really shouldn't)

Comment: But JWT Token used in application is supporting the “none” algorithm as a valid token with a verified signature. Hackers are able to change the payload with the same verified signature. Is there any way to block the algorithm  type "none"?

Comment: Ok so you have actually modified the token and are then able to go change the user id etc. in the token? The token is still authenticated? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes the PEN test team were able to authenticate the token.

Comment: I'm gonna test this on an API a bit later, I need to see if I can replicate the issue.

Comment: Tried this and was unable to reproduce the issue on the latest .NET 6 version. I modified the token header to have alg: none and removed the x5t and kid properties from header. Then I swapped the oid property value in the body of the token and kept the original signature. Back-end returns a 401 to me, it fails authentication.